# use string as function

Tags: php

Im using a simple __call function , to dynamicly get and set my properties and im searching for a way to use something easier then this:

```
$setKey = "set".ucfirst($key);
$this->$setKey($foo);
```

is there a way to use something like

```
$this->"set".ucfirst($key)($foo);
```

Comment: `$this->{"set".ucfirst($key)}($foo)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have to use braces:

```
$this->{"set".ucfirst($key)}($foo);
```

Comment: Thanks it works! now my code looks atleast a bit better!
I´ll accept your answer after the timer has finished!